# Css positioning and media query

Tags: css, media-queries

I am trying to make a simple responsive webpage and for that i need some way to resolve my issue - [image: Page with some appreciable space for the logo]

Now when i resize the window and see

[image: page after resizing]

Now what i want is that this logo not to fload downwards but, stay there and scroll with the rest of the body.

Here is my html

```
<ul id="gn-menu" class="gn-menu-main" style="z-index:99">
            <li class="gn-trigger">
                <a class="gn-icon gn-icon-menu"><span>Menu</span></a>
                <nav class="gn-menu-wrapper">
                    <div class="gn-scroller">
                        <ul class="gn-menu">
                            <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-download">Home</a></li>                            
                            <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-cog">Us</a></li>                                                            
                            <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-download">MSR Scenes</a></li>
                            <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-cog">Literature</a></li>
                            <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-help">Music</a></li>
                            <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-cog">Food</a></li>
                            <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-download">Gaming</a></li>
                            <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-cog">Sci-Tech</a></li>
                            <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-help">Horoscopes</a></li>
                            <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-cog">Art</a></li>
                            <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-download">Comic</a></li>
                            <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-cog">Sports</a></li>
                            <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-help">Pop Culture</a></li>
                            <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-download">Free Advice</a></li>                          
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /gn-scroller -->
                </nav>
            </li>
            <li style="position:relative"><img src="images/logo_01.jpg" width="230" height="90" style="z-index:-1" class="logo" ></li>
            <li><a id="us" >Us</a></li>
            <li><a id="home" ><span>Home</span></a></li>
        </ul>
```

and the list styling is as follows -

```
.gn-menu-main > li {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: 1px solid #c6d0da;
    text-align: center;
  }
.gn-menu-main > li:nth-child(1) {
    float: left;
    border-right: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #c6d0da;
  }

.gn-menu-main > li:nth-child(2) {
    float: left;
    border-right: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #c6d0da;
  }
```

Comment: You should upload your relevant code to http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Okay, sorry for the delay but i created the fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/iamdeadman/aWCuJ/ and when i resize then the logo floats downwards how do i fix this

Comment: 1. Why are you supporting such small resolutions? I don't think they even exists. 2. What are you expecting to happen? There's not enough place for both the button and the logo

Comment: I was kind of thinking about mobile devices, thats why i thought of acoomodating these small resolutions, and i know there wont be place left for the menu buttons for the small resolutions , thats why i set their property to display:none for small resolutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [`min-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width) property of the entire menu.

```
#gn-menu {
    min-width: 300px;   
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/aWCuJ/3/)

Comment: hhmm...i dont think its gonna satisfy the user because it simply hiding the overflowed elements in menu bar..i think resize will be a better option

Comment: @RitabrataGautam I think not supporting microscopic resolutions is the best option. :) And to be honest, if the OP doesn't say what he's expecting to happen we're not supposed to guess.

Comment: Okay ty resize works, though what i was thinking was to hide the menu items 'home' and 'us' and fill the screen with the logo and sorry itay had to go for lunch.....

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. You wanted the logo to stay on top and it does.

Comment: sorry @RitabrataGautam but i did not want to resize here since that would make the logo smaller, which i do not want as it would make my logo less focussing

Comment: youir design your concerns..if you want to hide menu items when resized then follow what itay said

Answer (score 1):

i think you should change the logo image size using media query to fit it in the same place in small screen and you may also need to change the font size , padding etc with media query if you want to fit the menu in small screen size

```
.img{
  width:100px;height:100px;
}
@media screen and(max-width:480px)
{
   .img{
      width:50px;
      height:50px;
    }
 }
```

this is happening because when you are resizing your browser your img size is getting too large to fit in the same line

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to overhang? If you don't mind keeping it inline, you could do: `max-height: 100%; width: auto;` which would keep it inside the bounds of the menu bar.

Comment: It's really unclear where do you want him to place these stylings.

Comment: I want to place the logo fill the screen , if the screen size is relatively small and not able to accomodate the menu items.

Comment: Yeah , but i tried placing them at the root unordered list and found that it aint working